# can't instantiate singleton with `factory-method`

Tags: java, xml, spring, perfectjpattern

I had a piece of code working that integrated Hibernate 3.3.2.GA and Spring 2.5.x and these versions were old so I decided to upgrade. I first upgraded Spring to the latest available version 3.2.0.RELEASE and this worked. Actually the working project with the latest Spring version may be checked out using `svn co https://perfectjpattern.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/perfectjpattern/trunk perfectjpattern`. Trying to upgrade to Hibernate 4 I get a different Spring beans behavior that eludes me and it is apparently unrelated to Hibernate 4.

The failing bean configuration is below. The full working configuration using Hibernate 3 is [here](http://perfectjpattern.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/perfectjpattern/trunk/perfectjpattern-spring/src/test/resources/test-applicationContext.xml?revision=1036&content-type=text/plain) (I haven't checked in the failing one using Hibernate 4 ofc):

```
<bean id="localDaoFactory" class="org.perfectjpattern.jee.integration.dao.LocalDaoFactory"  
    factory-method="getInstance">
    <property name="sessionStrategy">
        <ref bean="daoSessionStrategy" />
    </property>     
    <property name="transactionStrategy">
        <ref bean="daoTransactionStrategy" />
    </property>         
    <property name="personDao">
        <ref bean="personDao" />
    </property>     
</bean>
```

and the stacktrace of the exception is shown below, meaning it could not initialize `org.perfectjpattern.jee.integration.dao.LocalDaoFactory` and apparently it fails while looking for accessible constructors BUT in this configuration I specify to use a factory-method and not to instantiate the bean directly. This worked before upgrading Hibernate but not after and for the same Spring (latest) version which is very confusing.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:157)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:313)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:284)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:53)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:107)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:68)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'localDaoFactory' defined in URL [file:src/test/resources/test-applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.perfectjpattern.jee.integration.dao.LocalDaoFactory
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:581)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1029)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:925)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:490)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:607)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:106)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:57)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:100)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:248)
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.loadApplicationContext(TestContext.java:124)
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:148)
        ... 30 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.perfectjpattern.jee.integration.dao.LocalDaoFactory
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:160)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:570)
        ... 47 more
```

UPDATE: while loading the Spring configuration, Spring can't find the class `LocalDaoFactory` but it did before ...

UPDATE: this is the result of running `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose` and there are no unresolved conflicts

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:tree (default-cli) @ perfectjpattern-spring ---
[INFO] perfectjpattern:perfectjpattern-spring:jar:1.0.3-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- perfectjpattern:perfectjpattern-api:jar:1.0.3-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:3.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.0.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:3.2.0.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.2.0.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:3.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.0.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:3.2.0.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:3.2.0.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.2.0.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:3.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.0.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.2.0.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- (aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.0.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.2.0.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.0.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.2.0.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.0.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.2.0.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:3.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.0.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.2.0.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.2.0.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.0.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:3.2.0.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:3.2.0.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.2.0.RELEASE:test - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.0.RELEASE:test - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.2.0.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.2.0.RELEASE:test - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.0.RELEASE:test - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.2.0.RELEASE:test - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:test - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.2.0.RELEASE:test - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.2.0.RELEASE:test - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.2.0.RELEASE:test - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.0.RELEASE:test - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- perfectjpattern:perfectjpattern-testcommon:jar:1.0.3-SNAPSHOT:test
[INFO] |  +- junit:junit:jar:4.8.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.2:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.2:test
[INFO] |  |  \- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:test
[INFO] |  \- org.easymock:easymock:jar:2.5.2:test
[INFO] +- org.hsqldb:hsqldb:jar:2.2.9:test
[INFO] \- perfectjpattern:perfectjpattern-hibernate:jar:1.0.3-SNAPSHOT:test
[INFO]    +- perfectjpattern:perfectjpattern-jee:jar:1.0.3-SNAPSHOT:test
[INFO]    |  +- perfectjpattern:perfectjpattern-core:jar:1.0.3-SNAPSHOT:test
[INFO]    |  |  +- (perfectjpattern:perfectjpattern-api:jar:1.0.3-SNAPSHOT:test - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  |  +- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.2:test - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  |  \- (commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.5:test - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-ejb_3.0_spec:jar:1.0.1:test
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jpa_3.0_spec:jar:1.1.1:test
[INFO]    |  \- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jta_1.1_spec:jar:1.1.1:test
[INFO]    +- javassist:javassist:jar:3.8.0.GA:test
[INFO]    +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:test
[INFO]    \- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.1.9.Final:test
[INFO]       +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:test
[INFO]       +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.0.GA:test
[INFO]       +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.17.1-GA:test
[INFO]       +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:test
[INFO]       +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:test
[INFO]       +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:jar:1.0.1.Final:test
[INFO]       \- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:4.0.1.Final:test
[INFO]          \- (org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.0.CR2:test - omitted for conflict with 3.1.0.GA)
```

Comment: Please check that your LocalDaoFactory does not do anything in its static initializer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message `Could not initialize class org.perfectjpattern.jee.integration.dao.LocalDaoFactory` means that the JVM has been unable to statically initialize the class with this name.

I looked at [source of this class](http://perfectjpattern.sourceforge.net/clover/org/perfectjpattern/jee/integration/dao/LocalDaoFactory.html) and its superclasses [HibernateDaoFactory](http://perfectjpattern.sourceforge.net/clover/org/perfectjpattern/jee/integration/dao/HibernateDaoFactory.html#HibernateDaoFactory) and [AbstractDaoFactory](http://perfectjpattern.sourceforge.net/clover/org/perfectjpattern/jee/integration/dao/AbstractDaoFactory.html#AbstractDaoFactory).  The only static initialization done by LocalDaoFactory and HibernateDaoFactory is to create a single instance of each class and store it in a `private static final` field named `INSTANCE`.  So, there must be a problem instantiating these singletons.

LocalDaoFactory has no constructor of its own, and AbstractDaoFactory's constructor uses only standard Java classes and ones in the same package as it.  HibernateDaoFactory's constructor is a little more interesting, in that it creates a [HibernateCurrentSessionStrategy](http://perfectjpattern.sourceforge.net/clover/org/perfectjpattern/jee/integration/dao/HibernateCurrentSessionStrategy.html#HibernateCurrentSessionStrategy) and a [HibernateConfiguredTransactionStrategy](http://perfectjpattern.sourceforge.net/clover/org/perfectjpattern/jee/integration/dao/HibernateConfiguredTransactionStrategy.html#HibernateConfiguredTransactionStrategy).  The code itself doesn't look particularly problematic, so it seems likely that some of the classes that this code is trying to instantiate are missing.

The only dependencies that I could see on code outside PerfectJPattern were:

- Hibernate Core,
- Apache Commons Lang.

I'm going to assume that you do have the relevant Hibernate core JAR, so that leaves the finger of blame pointing at Apache Commons Lang.

The [Apache Commons Lang website](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) mentions that commons-lang version 3 uses a different package to earlier versions of commons-lang.  Given that your project worked before upgrading to Hibernate 4 and now doesn't work, I'm going to guess that upgrading to Hibernate 4 replaces commons-lang 2.6 or earlier with commons-lang 3 or later, and the problem arises because PerfectJPattern has a dependency on commons-lang 2.

**EDIT**: it looks like your project does include commons-lang v2.5, so the absence of that would seem not to be the problem.  A `NoClassDefFoundError` with  message `Could not initialize class ...` means that the JVM has tried and failed to load the class *at least twice* - if you could get hold of the exception message when it failed for the first time, that might help you more.  I'm afraid all I can really suggest is to start your project under a debugger that has been set to break on exceptions.

Comment: Thank you. I am currently investigating but it doesn't look like this is the problem. In trunk I globally define the version for all dependencies and common-collections I use the 3.x same as hibernate.

Comment: @GiovanniAzua: I'm not sure I understand your comment.  Firstly, this issue relates to commons-lang, not commons-collections.  Secondly, I can see that your code depends on commons-lang v2 because it imports `org.apache.commons.lang.*`; in commons-lang v3 the package became `org.apache.commons.lang3.*`.  I've just downloaded the commons-lang v3 JAR and verified it doesn't contain any `org.apache.commons.lang.*` classes.

Comment: It works on the Eclipse IDE project created with Maven while running it from command line produces the same issue ...

Comment: @GiovanniAzua: well, try using a command line debugger such as [jdb](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jdb.html), then.  I think the `catch` command in jdb may be what you need to use.

Comment: OK solved it. The issue was related to having several non abstract base classes that would greedily initialize the singleton instance, I moved to lazy singleton initialization and now works. Basically I was setting up the dataSource and SessionFactory from Spring while the HibernateDaoFactory was trying to get the pure Hibernate configuration.